# Unable to reach long playlist with pytube

Tags: python, pytube

I'm trying to download videos from youtube using pytube, but with some playlists I get the error  `urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found`. I think this may happen with long playlists; I have tried with playlist of up to fifteen videos without problems, but when it has ~200 videos or more the program raises this error.
Also: I was able to download up to one hundred videos from a 3000 playlist until a few weeks ago when I got the error. Here is my code:

```
from pytube import YouTube
from pytube import Playlist

playlist = Playlist("https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLSgg-eG6fBw3oCSMIjhV3dIkY2drNlHYR")


print(len(playlist.video_urls)) # This also happens if I try to download videos from the playlist
```

Maybe it is important to mention that a few days before I got this error I was temporarly banned from downlading videos, but three days later I was able to keep downloading.

Comment: Are you sure that it's the right URL?

Comment: Yes, I have tried with different playlist and copying the URL many times